# Is Ayase actually Kyousuke's sister, not Kirino?

Tags: oreimo

I haven't watched to the end of *OreImo*, but someone told me that Ayase is actually Kyousuke's sister, not Kirino. Is this true? Can anyone lend credence to this theory?

Comment: The question does not have a good enough basis. A baseless rumour without any reference nor proof that such a thing is common among the fans should not be put into question since it would only create a poor question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No? This notion is just false. Kirino and Kyousuke are siblings; Ayase is unrelated to them.

(Can't really prove a negative, I guess, but there is zero evidence to suggest that Ayase and Kyousuke are related. Would've been quite a twist if they were.)